# Javascript code in Chrome extension with wrong charset encoding?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, character-encoding

I'm fighting with some literal strings in my JS file.
When I edit them in my IDE I can see chars like "ó" without problem, the file is UTF-8, but when I test in the chrome extension the JS code from Chrome Dev Tools is showing weird chars like "Ã³" (in the code!).
And this was not happening before, I'm a bit lost about what could be causing this, any clue?

**EDIT:**
OK, I fixed it by adding charset="utf-8" to the script tag, but I'm curious about why is this happening, because I was using the same JS file without problem many times before on the same extension.

Comment: Without a reproducible [MCVE](/help/mcve) or a link to the actual extension the question isn't really answerable. It could be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I was thinking this could be a common problem, I mean I never set the charset in my script tags and they just work fine, but maybe I was lucky before and we always need to set UTF-8? and if not, when is needed?

Comment: Still sounds like a probable bug in Chrome.

Comment: Might be similar to https://crbug.com/968076. Try saving the file with utf8 BOM.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Just add

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

inside `<head>` tag